# Quasi-primary fields and usual fields

Tags: conformal-field-theory, tensor-calculus

How do i see that the way quasi-primary/[primary fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_field) transform  contain the transformation rule for fields as we know it (scalar, vector fields) in QFT?

Comment: Have you written down the transformation of a (quasi-)primary field and *looked* at it?

Comment: Yes I have. $A_j(x)->|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}|^{\frac{\Delta_j}{d}}A_j(x')$ and $A_j(x)->\frac{\partial x^{k}}{\partial x'^{j}} A_{k}(x')$. I can see they are similar but not able to make the complete connection